# Deploy dash dashboard on own infrasturcture

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am a newbie to Python Dash.

I want to build a dashboard,where I need to pull data from MySQL create a dashboard and deploy it on own MS Server 2012.

How can I deploy the dashboard on MS Server 2012.

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Snehal

Answer (score 7):

Dash is very easy to deploy and you just need to provide the server address/IP in the last call of dash :

This is by default run the app on localhost on your machine :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

So if your Server IP is 10.11.12.13 then use :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='10.11.12.13')
```

To know the IP address use ipconfig in your terminal if you are on windows. You can also provide the hosted ip to other users so that they can also access the same app.

Comment: Or you can just use `0.0.0.0` to listen on all interfaces